# Using Pandas-Profiling in AWS Glue

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-glue-data-catalog, pandas-profiling

I am trying to use pandas profiling in AWS Glue. I downloaded the wheel file and used it in the Glue Library Path. BUt whenever I am trying to run a pandas profiling, module missing error is coming up(like multimethod, visions, networkx, pillow and more).

What should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you've installed all dependencies from `requirements.txt`: https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/develop/requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

To install `pandas-profiling` library in Glue job

Goto - Job details -> Advanced properties -> Job parameters
Add key as `--additional-python-modules` and value as `pandas-profiling`
and save the changes.

Sharing the screenshot of the same below:
[image]

After this setting `pandas-profiling` library will be installed and then code will start execution.